# html5 communication with server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In traditional web application i generally write JSP which renders html code to browser and communicate to server using form submit or through Java script. This generally involves page transition from one to another using browser refresh many times.

Now with the improved HTML5 i still can use the same approach but i want to achieve more of a desktop application look and feel which means no browser refresh. But i am really confused how it can be achieved.

1. Do i need to write a big single html5 file which contains all the web application code and show or hide divisions using java script that we need to show at that point of time. Communicate to server using java script.
2. Or, Just have a minimal first html5 page where user lands for the first time. Later on create all the HTML5 content dynamically using java script and communicate to server using java script. This looks more difficult.
3. Or, is there a way we can move from one page to other without the effect of page loading/refresh etc.

In general using HTML5 what should be the approch?

For example of a shopping cart, the first view to the user is list of items to purchase. Then user moves to next view such as details of an item. The next view can be payment.

If you have some resource or example to explain it, it would be great.

Comment: Have a look at HTML5 History API. Before HTML5 you could already do this via AJAX so it is not really a HTML5 thing.

Comment: Using ajax i can change the current html file content. But how do i change the next page contents which i want to load. for example moving from list of items(1st HTML) to product details(2nd HTML) using ajax

Comment: You just load that next page in with AJAX and display the content that comes from that file in your current file.

Comment: `$("body").html(response);`